# Why do Azure Subscriptions require registrations with Providers?

Tags: azure, cloud

I have been trying to do some work with a brand new Azure subscription and same operations were failing with errors along the lines of `error:   The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Storage'.`

On the portal I could see links that took me to a page where I can register the subscription with a bunch of providers.

Why are Azure subscription required to register to providers? What's the concept behind this? And why would a subscription not be registered with all providers automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the concept behind that, but you can register all of them (with appropriate permissions) once for your subscription and forget about it.

```
$providers = @(Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable)
foreach ($x in $providers) {

Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace $x.ProviderNamespace -Force
write-host $x.ProviderNamespace
}
Write-Host “Done!”
```

From my understanding registering providers is like accepting the EULA.
[Azure Cli way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/azure-cli-arm-commands?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json#azure-provider-commands-to-manage-resource-provider-registrations)